# how to make border in gridview and background image in android?

Tags: android, gridview, border

I make a gridview to display days of month but i want to make a background with image and all grid items have a white border .. the same in this image

[image]

**This is my code in layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"      
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:horizontalSpacing="-1dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="-1dp"
         />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and where is grid item adapter layout?

Comment: there is no layout for grid item .. i fill it dynamically with text

Comment: You need to white the custom layout for this layout to achieve. Otherwise it is not possible I think